# NodeJS/MongoDB - Clone Collection with Indexs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, coffeescript

I'm trying to clone a mongodb collection with the indexs from two different MongoDB instances. After googling around, I found that [cloneCollection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/cloneCollection/#dbcmd.cloneCollection) would be my best bet. I've tried to make my code nice and simple, but I never seem to get the actual clone command to run. 'Started' and 'Authed' pop up in my console, but the command never runs. What is it I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
mongodb = require("mongodb")

#####################
# MONGODB CONFIG
#####################
console.log "Started"
Server = mongodb.Server
Db = mongodb.Db

server = new Server("example.com", 27017, {})
db = new Db("databaseTwo", server,
    safe: true
)

db.open (err, db) ->
    db.authenticate "user", "password", (err, res) ->
        throw err if err
        console.log "Authed"

db.command
    cloneCollection: "databaseOne.helloThereCollection"
    from: "example.com:6001"
    key:
        username: 'user'
        password: 'password'
, (err, cb) ->
    console.log err if err
    console.log 'Command Ran'
    cb null
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576541/clone-database-in-mongodb-between-hosts-using-node-driver).  Try using [`db.admin.command()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/admin.html#command)

Comment: Not a dup. He's trying to clone an entire data, myself just a collection with indexs. Gave it a shot, admin doesn't have a method "command". I would think my script above would atleast spit out an error if there was a collection/database problem.

Comment: ah ok, my bad! it isn't a dup.

Comment: Maybe not a duplicate, but you **did notice** the "command" is run **inside** the "open" callback didn't you? So what do you think happens when something like this is **outside** of that callback?

Comment: Try moving the db.command inside the db.open callback. I think the process may be exiting before that command callback is run. You're not getting errors, is it cloning the collection but not running the console logs ("Command Ran")?