# Copy Database in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How can I copy a database to another in Mongoose? something like this command line:

`db.copyDatabase('sourceDb','destinationDb')` ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct possibility in mongoose. The easiest way seems to be using the [mongodb native client](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) in parallel. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576541/clone-database-in-mongodb-between-hosts-using-node-driver).