# How can I execute db.copyDatabase through NodeJS's MongoDB native driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I do have a shell script that invokes

```
mongo --eval "db.copyDatabase('somedatabase', 'somedatabase_duplicate', 'sourcehost')"
```

to copy a database.

Currently I am stuck with doing the same from within a Node.JS application. Calling

```
mongoCommand = `db.copyDatabase("somedatabase", "somedatabase_duplicate", "localhost")`;
db.command(mongoCommand, function(commandErr, data) {
      if(!commandErr) {
        log.info(data);
      } else {
        log.error(commandErr.errmsg);
      }
    });
```

Always resulsts in a "no such command" error message.

Edit for clarification: Using db.admin().command() results in the same problem and using the command suggested in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576541), too.

What's the correct way to call this command or, alternatively, to clone a database from Node.JS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clone database in Mongodb between hosts using node driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576541/clone-database-in-mongodb-between-hosts-using-node-driver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you are trying to copy database which is administration operation so have to do with admin account. Again, to copy database command is `copydb`.

try running this command in shell, `db.copyDatabase` and you'll see source of command.

try:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {

        var mongoCommand = { copydb: 1, fromhost: "localhost", fromdb: "test", todb: "test_dup" };
        var admin = db.admin();

        admin.command(mongoCommand, function(commandErr, data) {
            if (!commandErr) {
                console.log(data);
            } else {
                console.log(commandErr.errmsg);
            }
            db.close();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything. The callback is never run. node just exits and I see nothing in the MongoDB logs.

Comment: Check if you have database copy on your server? Also make sure you have permissions to access admin database. In my case, I see message `{ ok: 1 }`

Comment: I  get zero output and no new database. When using the batch file, it works. That's what I can't wrap my head around.

Comment: What versions of node / driver / mongodb did this work with?  I just tried this with node.js 9.11.1, mongodb (npm package) 3.1.1, mongo (shell) 3.2.6 and it gave me `db.admin is not a function`

Comment: @Wyck try: db.mongodb.db.admin

Answer (score 0):

```
//core modules
const assert = require('assert')
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const moment = require('moment');
const mongo = require('mongodb')

//custom modules
let { ip, port, database } = require('./dbUpgradeConfig')
const url = `mongodb://${ip}:${port}`
let todayDate = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')
console.log(todayDate)
const myDate = new Date()
console.log(myDate)
var d = Date(Date.now());
// Converting the number of millisecond in date string 
a = d.toString()

// Options for mongoDB
const mongoOptions = { useNewUrlParser: true }
let db


//TODO: handle reconnect
let connect = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (db) resolve()
        else {
            mongo.connect(url, mongoOptions, (err, client) => {
                if (err) reject(err)
                else {
                    db = client.db(database)
                    resolve()
                }
            })
        }
    })
}


/**
 * @description create duplicate database from current database in mongodb 
 */
let CloneDb = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connect()
            .then(() => {
                console.log(db)
                let mongoCommand = { copydb: 1, fromhost: "localhost", fromdb: "db_name", todb: "db_name_duplicate" }
                let adminDB = db.admin()

                adminDB.command(mongoCommand, function (commandErr, data) {
                    if (!commandErr) {
                        console.log(data)
                    } else {
                        console.log(commandErr.errmsg)
                    }

                });
            })
    })
}

CloneDb().then(data => {
    // debugger;
    console.log("The clone db", data)
})
```