# MongoError: listCollections failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I have setted up a mongo database, which works with authentication.

I'm trying to copy a database using [mongodb native driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native).

---

The problem is my command get rejected as :

```
MongoError: listCollections failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "not authorized on SESSION to execute command { listCollections: 1, filter: { $or: [ { type: "collection" }, { type: { $exists: false } } ] }, cu...", code: 13, codeName: "Unauthorized" }
```

---

Here is how I run my database :

```
/usr/bin/mongod --quiet
                --setParameter authenticationMechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-1
                --auth
                --port 27017
                --dbpath /database
```

---

Here is the user I'm using to connect

```
  db.createUser({
      "user": "USER",
      "pwd": "PASS",
      "roles": [ "root" ]
  });
```

I also tried using :

```
  db.createUser({
      "user": "USER",
      "pwd": "PASS",
      "roles": [ { "role": "root", "db": "admin" } ]
  });
```

---

Here is how I connect (the connection succeed) :

```
const url = "mongodb://USER:PASS@172.42.0.2:27017/SESSION?authSource=admin";

MongoClient.connect(url, ...
```

---

Here is how I request the copy :

```
const mongoCommand = {
     copydb: 1,
     fromhost: "172.42.0.2",
     fromdb: "SESSION",
     todb: "SESSION_COPY",
};

// Perform the copy
this.db.admin().command(mongoCommand, function (err, data) {
```

---

I am using :

```
Mongodb (database) v3.4.7
Mongodb (node package) v2.2.31
```

---

Thanks :)

---

Some posts that get me through this :

[mongodb-not-authorized-for-query-admin-system-users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067612/mongodb-not-authorized-for-query-admin-system-users)

[how-can-i-execute-db-copydatabase-through-nodejss-mongodb-native-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403749/how-can-i-execute-db-copydatabase-through-nodejss-mongodb-native-driver)

Comment: None of those users have been granted access to the `SESSION` database . There is actually a property for that. In fact you used it, and it's `db`. You only granted permission on `admin`.

Comment: The first user have `"roles": [ "root" ]` which is supposed to grant `root` rights on every collection right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so first of all, here is the [copydb command mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/copydb/#dbcmd.copydb).

[image]

We can see there that in case of using `fromhost` you need to specify `username`,`nouce` and `key`.

---

**SOLUCE**

If you want to copy a database in the same host: **Do not use of** `fromhost`.

*Example* :

```
const mongoCommand = {
    copydb: 1,
    fromdb: "SESSION",
    todb: "SESSION_SAVE",
};
```

---

If you want to copy a database using different hosts: Use of `username`, `nonce` and `key` [here is how you create them](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/copydb/#copydb-nonce-key).